# base64_encode conflicts with convert_smilies in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I am trying to show an image on my Wordpress website that I get from a third-party. They give me the raw data of the image. To show the image, I need to convert the raw data (which I get from the third-party) to base64. It was working perfectly, but recently I got an error with a specific image. For all other images, it is working perfectly.
I have debugged it and found the issue was created by `base64_encode($file)`.

**My Code :**

```
$file = "image raw data which get form third-party";
$type = "image type"; // png, jpg, jpeg
$en_data = base64_encode($file);
<img src="data:image/<?=$type;?>;base64, <?= $en_data; ?> ">
```

**Error :**

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be
> of type Countable|array, bool given in
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-includes\formatting.php:3415 Stack
> trace: #0
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(307):
> convert_smilies('\r\n<style type="...') #1
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-includes\plugin.php(191):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters('\r\n<style type="...', Array) #2
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-includes\post-template.php(253):
> apply_filters('the_content', '<!-- wp:shortco...') #3
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-content\plugins\my-plugin\pagetemplate\page_fullwidth-template.php(11):
> the_content() #4
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-includes\template-loader.php(106):
> include('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #5
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-blog-header.php(19):
> require_once('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #6
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\index.php(17):
> require('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #7 {main} thrown in
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-includes\formatting.php on line 3415
>
> There has been a critical error on this website.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, bool given` this is clear that there is something wrong with the $value

Comment: Hi @Akam, yes the issue with count() function and $value, but it's comes from wordpress core file not from my code and I can not update in wordpress core file.

Comment: Do you need the functionality that `convert_smilies` provides? If not, might be best to simply disable that.

Comment: Hi CBro
convert_smilies is wordpress core function and I can not update in wordpress core file.

Comment: No one said anything about updating WP core files, I was referring to exactly the solution now provided in your answer. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/269983

Answer (score 3):

I have also asked this question in wordpress.stackexchange, and [Rup](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/3276/rup) provided a solution and it's working for me.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies', 20 );
```

Full answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/409084/base64-encode-conflict-with-convert-smilies-in-wordpress/409087#409087).

Thanks Rup :)

Comment: In our case, we don't need smilies at all, so it was easy/better to clear the `use_smilies` option, which is another suggested solution in the linked article by Rup.